# Doctrine says primary key is not defined when column is both PK and FK

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have an Entity that has a column that is both a primary and a foreign key.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * BlacklistedUserIds
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="blacklisted_user_ids")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BlacklistedUserIds
{
    /**
     * @var \Orm\Entity\UserAccounts
     *
     * @Orm\Id @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Orm\Entity\UserAccounts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_account_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)
     * })
     */
    private $userAccount;
}
```

Doctrine console does not like this Entity though as it does not seem to recognize @Orm\Id bit in

```
@Orm\Id @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Orm\Entity\UserAccounts")
```

Here is my console output

```
[vagrant@dev api]$ doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql



  [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                            
  No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Orm\Entity\BlacklistedUserIds". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.  



orm:schema-tool:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [--force]
```

According to http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-1-dynamic-attributes my definition should be totally valid.

What is that I am missing?

Thanks